# VBA code to auto save a copy of my workbook as read only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that multiple people work out of and edit, however I would like to be able to save my edits without having to 'save as' constantly. I came up with the below code to save a copy of the workbook in a differently location, but how could I save it as a read only file, that won't get edited every time someone goes in and hits the save button?

thanks in advance.

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal _
  SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SaveCopyAs ("G:\Admin\AG\backup of " & .Name)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you only want this to work for you but not for others then you'd need to change your code so it "knows" who is doing the saving...

Answer (score 1):

I've used something along these lines in the past

```
Sub SetFileReadOnly(strPath As String)

Dim o As Object
Dim fl As Object

Set o = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

Set fl = o.getfile(strPath)
fl.Attributes = 1

Set o = Nothing
Set fl = Nothing

End Sub
```